# jQuery.ProfanityFilter count

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, profanity

I am using jQuery.ProfanityFilter to find swear words in a page. The code is below:

```
$divs.profanityFilter({
            customSwears: ['drunk'],
            externalSwears: 'swearWords.json',
            filter: false,
            profaneText: function (data) {

                alert("swear!");
            }
        });
```

My question is would there be any way of counting the amount of swear words that are found?  I cannot seem to find a suitable way of adapting the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just add a variable for a counter, and inside the `profraneText` function, increment

Comment: You probably want to `console.log()` out the `data` parameter of that function, I expect there's probably an array of the matched profanity in there somewhere.

Comment: @DBS [it seems so](https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/jQuery.ProfanityFilter/blob/master/jquery.profanityfilter.js#L194), but it doesn't contains all matches, just one for each word, as it uses `.unique` on the array.

Comment: Why not just modify the plugin file directly then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to modify your plugin slightly. Based on the [link](https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/jQuery.ProfanityFilter/blob/master/jquery.profanityfilter.js#L194) presented by @DontVoteMeDown, you may be able to manually change the `profaneText` function in the plugin file directly to work with your implementation of it.

**In the Plugin File**

```
if (profane) {
  options.profaneText(data.unique(), data.length);
};
```

Then in your own JQuery implementation of the plugin:

```
$divs.profanityFilter({
        customSwears: ['drunk'],
        externalSwears: 'swearWords.json',
        filter: false,
        profaneText: function (data, size) {
          console.log("Swear words in element: " + data);
          console.log("Number of swear words: " + size);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global counter variable.

```
var swears = 0;

$divs.profanityFilter({
  customSwears: ['drunk'],
  externalSwears: 'swearWords.json',
  filter: false,
  profaneText: function (data) {
    swears++;
    alert("swear!");
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think it runs that function on every match, rather it runs once if there are any matches.